# If I use apache for a reverse proxy and access it with https, are the web applications protected

Tags: apache, servlets, ssl, https, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache server running a LAMP stack with Apache 2.4.4. I have a few web applications running in different Tomcat servlets on different ports e.g.: www.example.com:8180, www.example.com:8280

On my apache server I have the following set up for my reverse proxy configuration

```
    ProxyPass /webapp1 _http://www.example.com:8180/webapp1_
    ProxyPassReverse /webapp1 http://www.example.com:8180/webapp1

    ProxyPass /webapp2 http://www.example.com:8280/webapp2
    ProxyPassReverse /webapp2 http://www.example.com:8280/webapp2
```

Everything seems to check out I can access *http://www.example.com/webapp1* and *https://www.example.com:8443/webapp1*

The web applications servlets do not have https enabled.

When using the *https://www.example.com:8443/webapp1* am I really using the https protocol with the pages on webapp1 the information between the user and the webapp1 encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are using HTTPS between the browser and Apache HTTPD, and HTTP between that and Tomcat. However if you've done it right Tomcat *thinks* it's HTTP, has the client certificate available (if any), etc.